# How do i reference something in the play framework sbt file?

Tags: playframework

If my dependence is this:

```
"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1"
```

ie

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1"
)
```

Then what is the resolver meant to look like - and how would i find a different, um, version?

I have this as my resolver (same file, next line):

```
resolvers += "Maven (sontaype) Repository" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

Don't ask me why maven repo is called sonatype, that's dumb! Anyway, how can i find out what versions to put as the dependency? I don't want to use snapshot - but the link i have *is*, which is stupid (why would anyone use snapshot?) - how can i get stable releases?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh! Who makes this stuff?

I'm still not sure how it works - play does things magically, and honestly i wish it wouldn't.

Anyway - as in my question, only some fool tutorial used the snapshot release (never ever, ever use a snapshot release. Always use stable! There is never a reason to use snapshot!)

So you now have:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.4-for-play24"
)

resolvers += "Maven (sontaype) Repository" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
```

Ok, so we're pointing at stable - now for our case, you'd go to

```
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases
```

then "ws", then "securesocial", and now play does magic - it seems to "know" to look at 2.11? I'm not sure why, it just does. So I went into "2.11" , and then selected

"2.1.4-for-play24"

Because why not? I'm not even sure if this thing is still being developed, or why it is for 2.4 and not 2.5 or 2.6!!!

Comment: A) You're ranting about SBT features, not Play. B) The operator is one of the [better documented parts of the system](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTDependencies#Getting-the-right-Scala-version-with-%%). C) [It is mostly dead, there are some forks out there](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/issues/589) that are still maintained and are compatible with the latest versions.